# onClick is not working in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter-3

When I try to use `onClick` in the php page like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="deleteCourse('<?php echo $row->courseId;?>');" class="delete">Delete</a>
```

and in js page I used like:

```
function deleteCourse(course_id){
    alert('trying to delete course');
 },
```

It will shows error like

> Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteCourse is not defined

at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick but when I use onClick in the same page its working properly.

### courselist.php

```
<?php if($deleteRole == 1){?>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="deleteCourse('<?php echo $row->courseId;?>');" class="delete">Delete</a>
<?php }?>
```

### user.js

```
function deleteCourse(course_id){
   alert('trying to delete course');
}
```

That user.js is included properly, I have seen it in page source.

Comment: Check your included js ordering. make sure your user.js included after your jquery js file.

Comment: //when I use onClick in the same page its working properly// What do you mean by this?

Comment: You got nothing to do with CI. Its clear javascript cannot find the function. Which points, your function is not loaded. Kindly recheck the page source properly whether you got the function in the user.js file.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene when i use that `deleteCourse ` function in the same courselist.php file, then it is working.

Comment: @GhanshyamBhava yes its included after all jquery files

Comment: @Kevin It means, your user.js file is not loaded properly with function delete course. Put a dummy alert in user.js and run the code. You should get the alert, which will confirm your user.js file is loaded. Then create a button tag and call the onclick function from that static button (without any php code)

Comment: As you have jquery, you could use $(document).on("click",".delete", function(){}).. I will post this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="deleteCourse('<?php echo $row->courseId;?>');" class="delete">Delete</a>
```

The intention of a tag is to redirect. If you are not redirecting, why you want to use a tag, instead i suggest you to button or li tags (if used in menu)

I am changing the attributes. The reason we go for jquery is to seperate HTML and JS codes. Dont use javascript codes inside HTML if you are using jquery.(A suggestion, which you might omit)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-courseId="<?php echo $row->courseId;?>" class="delete">Delete</a>
```

In user.js file (loaded after jquery file)

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 event.stopPropagation();
 courseId = $(this).attr("data-courseId");
 alert('trying to delete course');
//your logic for deleting the course.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="deleteCourse(<?php echo $row->courseId;?>);" class="delete">Delete</a>
```

You dont need to use quotes while passing integer to JS function